# map or unordered_map in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, hashmap, associative-array

I'd like to count occurrences of a pre-known set of chars in a string of text. My intuition is to create a std::map with those chars as values and values initialised at 0, like so:

```
unordered_map<char, int> charCounts {
    { 'a', 0 },
    { 'b', 0 },
    { 'c', 0 },
};
```

Iterating over each char in the input string with a `for` loop, and incrementing the value of a char if it is present in the map.

After the loop, I'd like to return the minimum value in the map.

I can see that in terms of efficiency, I either make trade-offs with lookup (checking if the char in my input string is in my map) or in obtaining the min value at the end, when it comes to using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. Which would be more suitable for my task?

Comment: Depents on many things, so if you have a performance requirement you will have to measure on your data. unordered_map can lookup faster, but it has to calculate hashes which can be more overhead etc. ect. So yes unordered map promises O(1) lookup and map O(log n), but the overhead of unordered map can be higher.

Comment: As key is `char`, `std::array<256, int>` is another option.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good call that.

Comment: map has O(log n) lookup; unordered_map O(c) but uses a hash. Container with indexed lookup is probably the fastest as Jarod42 points out. std::array has the extra benefit of memory locality.

Comment: I would consider an ordinary array, using the `char` values or a simple function thereof as indices.  I guess this is a deconstructed version of an ordered map.

Comment: If you need to optimize this code, an array of chars indexed by char values would be best, but if you're deciding between the other 2, you probably should do some benchmarking with both alternatives...

Comment: Also consider that if the chars are 'a' to 'z', log(26) is *really* small. And also that `O(1)` means "always takes about the same time", not "fastest in the world". Could also mean "always equally slow".

Comment: @JohnBollinger interesting idea but then when I'm iterating through my input string, I'd have to check if that character is part of the set of characters I'm looking for, which is less efficient than direct lookup using a map, no?

Currently I'm doing  as follows:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i) {
                if (charCounts.find(text[i]) != charCounts.end()) {
                    ++charCounts[text[i]];
                };
            };
```

Comment: @Jarod42 would  you mind explaining how this might work? Apologies, I'm early on my programming journey and don't follow!

Comment: `std::unordered_map` will have a **huge** space overhead compared to `std::array<256, int>` unless you have very few character values. And, of course, constant time (mostly) lookup doesn't address the fact that lookups in an unordered map are much slower than lookups in an array.

Comment: @DanielMaxwell, it would likely be most efficient to *not* check, instead keeping counts of all characters, then at the end to look at only the counts for the ones you care about.  But if you want to check in advance then there are multiple ways to make those checks much cheaper than a lookup in a map.

Answer (score 2):

One would need an awful lot of stats to find the best tradeoffs, taking into account the distribution of your input letters.

Intuitively if you need the order for the results just take a `map`: if using random lower and uppercase letters,  you'd have an average of 4 comparison per input letter, and a max of 52 inserts.

In comparison, the unordered map would have a hash calculation for every input letter, and I'd wonder if there wouldn't be some comparison for collision detection on buckets.  Same of 52 inserts, not to forget the sorting at the end.

If it's really about performance, you have at least another alternatives with  an array or a vector large enough to cope with the range `std::numeric_limits<char>::min()` and  `std::numeric_limits<char>::max()` , keeping in mind that `char` is not necessarily unsigned. This is a kind of manually optimised map with the O(1) benefit of unordered maps and the right order. This is a typical trick used by early lexers.

The option to sort the input string is another alternative,  but it might be more space and time consuming if it is a long string, than going for an unordered map and sort just a few letters at the end.

Comment: Upvoted for the obvious suggestion to use a vector.  However in practice the hash calculation for an integral type like char is just going to be the identity function and will be optimized out at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, for timing, you have to measure.

[quich-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/qvcKJu_APJUl3nvxCpWdlRJyt5k) (with short input string, to construct the frequency map) gives:

`std::array<std::size_t, 256>` < `std::map<unsigned char, std::size_t>` (~4.6 slower) < `std::unordered_map<unsigned char, std::size_t>` (~6.2 slower).

I suggest to adapt my code for more real data. you might also add code for retrieval of minimal (non-nul) count.

Comment: Thank you! That's a nice experimental confirmation :-)

Comment: Your input string is very short which is unfavorable for unordered_map's due to their slow construction. With 'lorem ipsum' I get about 400 for std::array; 10000 for std::map and 5800 for unordered_map.